# Is there a real life meaning about KMeans error?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, k-means

I am trying to understand the meaning of error in [sklearn KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

In the context of house pricing prediction, the error linear regression could be considered as the money difference per square foot.

Is there a real life meaning about KMeans error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The K-means Error gives you, what is known as, total intra-cluster variance. [image: K-means error]

**Intra-cluster variance** is the measure of how much are the points in a given cluster *spread*.

The following cluster will have **high intra-cluster variance**[image: sparse cluster]

In the image below, even though the number of points are same as that of the image above, the points are densely distributed and hence will have **lower intra-cluster variance**.
[image]

K-means Error is interested in the **total** of such individual cluster variances.

Suppose for a given data, if clustering 'A' forms clusters like the first image and clustering 'B' forms clusters like the second image, you will *in most cases* choose the second one.

Although this does not mean that the K-means Error is a perfect objective to optimize on to form clusters. But it pretty much catches the essence behind clustering.

---

**Code used for cluster plot generation -**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sparse_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[50000, 0], [0, 50000]], size=(1000))
plt.plot(sparse_samples[:, 0], sparse_samples[:, 1], 'b+')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim(-1000, 1000)
axes.set_ylim(-1000, 1000)
plt.show()

dense_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[5000, 0], [0, 5000]], size=(1000))
plt.plot(dense_samples[:, 0], dense_samples[:, 1], 'r+')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim(-1000, 1000)
axes.set_ylim(-1000, 1000)
plt.show()
```

In both cases, a `1000` datapoints from a [Bivariate Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) are  **sampled and plotted** . In the second case, the [Covariance Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is changed to plot a denser cluster. `np.random.multivariate_normal`'s documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your excellent explanation. do you mind post your code for the 2 figures?

Comment: Edited the answer to include the code used for plotting :)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "error" in k-Means clustering is: how much discrepancy / loss of information would you get if you substitute the k centroids to the actual observations. In other words: how good the k centroids approximate your data.

There are several ways you can measure this "error". Usually the **percentage of variance explained** or the **within cluster sum of errors** are employed, but the choice is huge. Even a more banal Euclidean distance could work.